# how to load external libraries into an SAPUI5 view?

Tags: sapui5

In SAPUI5 I can load local files this way:

```
jQuery.sap.require("util.someFile");
```

But is it possible to load external libraries when required in some view using the above command or a similar approach? Ideally, I am looking for something like:

```
theLoadingCommand("some_url");
```

Thanks

Comment: no, the other question asks how to load third party libraries that are already included with SAPUI5 framework. Here I am looking for a way to load external libraries for instance jQuery from Google API "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it is possible to register a module path to some URL.

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('external.library', 'http://....'); //not working
```

There is only one problem with that. UI5 loads the resources via AJAX requests. Your browser will give you an error because you are trying to load files from a different host.

You can include external libraries by including the file in a normal script tag. It is also possible to include requireJS in your project and use its features. Unfortunately, at the moment UI5 doesn't support requireJS out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is supported by SAPUI5, so you can extend your heading from controller, for example:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```