# SAPUI5: How to use external library in controller?

Tags: sapui5

In my index.html file I have the following code:

```
<script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("lodash","https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min");
        jQuery.sap.require("lodash");

        new sap.m.Shell({
            app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                height : "100%",
                name : "sap.com.ml.docservicedoc-service-m-learning"
            })
        }).placeAt("content");
    });
```

How can I now use lodash in one of my controllers (not view)? I tried:

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
"lodash"], function(Controller, _) {
```

Unfortunately "_" is always undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load external libraries into an SAP UI5 view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984423/how-to-load-external-libraries-into-an-sap-ui5-view)

Comment: The difference is that I want to use the lib in a controller, not a view. I already figured out the solution. Will post it now.

Answer (score 5):

Figured out a solution:

1. Create `libs` folder in your project and put the library into that folder
2. Inside your controller add the library as the following. Also keep in mind that the value in the define function should be different to the global name of the library:

```
sap.ui.define([
       "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
       "<project namespace>/libs/lodash/lodash.min",
   ], function(Controller, lodash) {
```

3. Use global root variable of library. In case of lodash it is "_"

Comment: why cannot we add it in the manifest.json file too? shouldnt that be a good practice?