# How to include threejs (external lib) within SAPUI5 app view controller correctly?

Tags: javascript, three.js, sapui5

**The problem**

How to include the library `three.js` in SAPUI5 so that I can use it like I normally do, using THREE as root variable in my main view controller?

I already tried to create a folder `libs` in my project directory and include it in my controller header like shown here: [SAPUI5: How to use external library in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464218/sapui5-how-to-use-external-library-in-controller)

Getting an error:

> THREE is undefined

[image]

Edit: It's the same for 'three' instead of 'THREE'.

There is also an experimental package within SAPUI5 `sap.ui.vk.threejs` which is kind of messy and seems not to be well documented.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Is it just in the WebIDE (ESLint) or also in the Dev console when actually running the app?

Comment: @Marc it's both actually. From Console it's: "can't get Scene from undefined".

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive, you are importing the parameter as 'three'. THREE is treated as a different variable

Comment: Even with the correct spelling I doubt that three.js uses the same AMD implementation like UI5. three is probably undefined anyway.